# remove specific record from array of records all in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mysql2

I am implementing search functionality in rails. When i search for users, the logged in user who is searching also comes in search. I want to avoid it.

This is in my search_method in controller

```
@matchedUsers = InUser.where("first_name like ?", "%#{params[:searchfnameInput]}%")
```

And i have user id in `session[:user_id]`. I want to exclude the record having `id==session[:user_id]` from `@matchedUsers`?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another where clause to your query:

```
@matchedUsers = InUser.where("id<>?", current_user.id).where("first_name like ?", "%#{params[:searchfnameInput]}%")
```

The "id<>?" says "exclude the user with this ID".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now as i wanted. Can you please tell what is this second clause doing and its syntax?

Comment: It's saying "give me the users except the one whose id is that of the current user"